# Testing a remote web service with soapUI

Tags: web-services, soapui

I have a Javax web service deployed in a remote Linux machine within a JBoss ESB container.  I am able to test the web service using soapUI on the same machine as where the service is deployed. The WDSL URI I used was something like `http://127.0.0.1:8080/abcd/abcd?wsdl`.

What I would like to do is to be able to test the same service from another machine using soapUI. I tried replacing `127.0.0.1` with the IP address of the machine where the service is deployed. This does not seem to work. Can someone tell me what I am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the service running and can the other machine connect to the first (not firewalled on port 8080)?

Answer (score 1):

a sum of things could go wrong there - as already mentioned by the others the firewall is blocking access for the given (address, port) pair. Another thing that happened to me was that the WSDL was generated using the name of the machine it was deployed on and whenever I was trying to call the service from a different machine it was complaining that I cannot find the given machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test network connectively.  One tool you can use is plain old `telnet`.  If you telnet to the ip/port combo of the web server, you will get a response (an HTTP error).  For example:

```
$ telnet 192.168.0.10 8080
```

If you get nothing then there is almost certainly a firewall blocking access.

If you are convinced that no firewall is blocking you, the other possibility is that the web server is only bound to the local network adapter (127.0.0.1) and not the other network adapters (ethernet/wifi).  This is very unlikely however.